# Getting details of binding errors for a JSON form in Spring MVC

Tags: java, json, spring, validation, spring-mvc

I use Spring MVC 3.2.4. I have a controller method that receives data from an HTML form. The method has the following signature:

```
@RequestMapping(...)
public String updateProduct(@Valid Product product, BindingResult bindingResult)
```

In the method, I can get information about both **data binding** (e.g., a non-integer value in an integer field) and **validation** (JSR-303) errors in the following way:

```
if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
    List<FieldError> errors = bindingResult.getFieldErrors();

    for (FieldError error : errors) {
        System.out.println(error.getObjectName() + " - " + error.getCode());
    }
}
```

I want to change this method so that it could receive data in JSON format instead of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. I added `@RequestBody` annotation to the method signature:

```
@RequestMapping(...)
public String updateProduct(@Valid @RequestBody Product product, BindingResult bindingResult)
```

In the updated method I still can get all **validation** errors in the same way. However, **data binding** errors generate an `HttpMessageNotReadableException`. The exception seems to have no properties for accessing things like the error code and field/object name. Besides, the exception prevents the JSR-303 validation, and the user does not receive any JSR-303 validation messages till the next data submission.

How can I get the information about **data binding** errors when I implement a controller method that receives JSON?

**UPDATE:**

One workaround that I can think of is changing all fields in the `Product` class to `String` and then validating them with JSR-303. This way, no **data binding** errors will ever happen. But I will have to create a clone of the `Product` class with proper data types.

Comment: Changing all fields to strings in our target object is unfortunately the work around I have also had to use for such cases. It would be nice to find a cleaner way to capture and report such errors more gracefully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't get confused, [`HttpMessageNotReadableException`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/HttpMessageNotReadableException.html) has nothing to do with validation errors. It gets thrown when an [`HttpMessageConverter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/HttpMessageConverter.html) cannot read an [`HttpInputMessage`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpInputMessage.html). With JSON, that probably means [`MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.html). It will throw that exception if something goes wrong while deserializing the JSON into an instance of whatever type you specified, `Product` in this case. This can happen if the JSON is malformed.

You cannot catch those errors in a `BindingResult`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Do you know any other way to catch them? I get this exception when JSON contains, for example, non-integer string in an integer field. It happens all the time when a user enters incorrect data in the form. I can get information on this errors when I use the first method signature. (I corrected `@ResponseBody`, it was a mistake in the question, not in my actual code.)

Comment: @Alexey Specifically because this is JSON, this error is not a validation error, it is a formatting error. The client sent a Bad Request. That's why the server handles it with a 400 status code. To the JSON parser this error is not much different than a missing `}` in the JSON. You should not be catching these errors. You should be fixing your client so that it follows your server's specification.

Comment: OK, thanks, I got it. However, my client sends the end-user input, and I do not want to validate the data on the client side. It means that I cannot use JSON. I'll wait to see it anyone can offer a solution, and if nobody does I'll accept you answer.

Comment: @Alexey If you cannot use JSON, why don't you use form-url-encoding as in your first example?

Comment: I can do that. I just thought it would be cool if I could have one REST (JSON) web service that can be accessible from both an AJAX web page and another client. I spent some time re-factoring my AJAX web page and now run into this problem :)

Comment: You can provide both with little work, have one controller method eat form data and one eat application/json

Comment: @Jukka, thanks, I can do it as well. But I would still prefer to have one common REST interface. And I probably can handle `HttpMessageNotReadableException` (as you suggested in another comment) but I am not sure if it has all information about the error that I need. I'll have a closer look at that exception.

Answer (score 1):

You ought to be using @RequestBody there. With that, validation errors will throw MethodArgumenNotValidException which you can handle in an @ExceptionHandler annotated method and return the validation error(s) in e.g. a JSON error object.

Comment: Thanks, I do use @RequestBody :) I just made a mistake while writing the question. I corrected it.

Comment: `MethodArgumenNotValidException` handles **validation** errors (I can handle them without a problem with either `BindingResult` or `MethodArgumenNotValidException`). The **data binding** errors throw `HttpMessageNotReadableException` which seem to have no properties for accessing things like the error code and field/object name.