# Get Missing Fields When HttpMessageNotReadableException occurs

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, kotlin

I have an API that expects the below dto structure.

```
data class SignupRequest(
    @NotEmpty(message ="Username must not be empty")
    @NotNull(message = "Username must not be null")
    val username: String,

    @NotEmpty(message ="Password must not be empty")
    @NotNull(message = "Password must not be null")
    val password: String,

    @NotEmpty(message ="Email must not be empty")
    @NotNull(message = "Email must not be null")
    val email: String
)
```

Below is the controller

```
@RestController
class AuthenticationController {
   @Autowired
   private lateinit var userRepository: UserRepository

   @PostMapping("/signup")
   @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
   fun signup(@Valid @RequestBody request: SignupRequest) : SignupResponse {
      val user = User(
            id = UUID.randomUUID(),
            username = request.username,
            password = request.password,
            email = request.email
    )

       try {
          userRepository.save(user)
          return SignupResponse(msg = "Success");
       } catch (e: Exception) {
          throw ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_GATEWAY, "Invalid fields", e)
       }
   }
}
```

When I make an API call if any one of the fields is missing or null I get the `HttpMessageNotReadableException`, and because the default error message doesn't make much sense to the client I try to format it by providing and error handler for that exception.

```
@RestControllerAdvice
class ApiExceptionHandler {

   @ExceptionHandler(HttpMessageNotReadableException::class)
   fun handleMessageNotReadableException(
        ex: HttpMessageNotReadableException,
        req: HttpServletRequest,
        res: HttpServletResponse
   ) : ResponseEntity<ApiError> {
       val error = ApiError();
       return ResponseEntity<ApiError>(error, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
   }

}
```

However, I also need to know the exact fields that are missing and while the default error message contains this information the exception object doesn't have it, I can't extend `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` either because then I have to provide implementations for all the default cases it handles.

How do I easily and correctly return the missing fields in API call

Comment: good question!, i hope there is some alternative to doing this manually now in 2020 (I still do them manually on my apps) .. question from 2015 --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21793584/getting-details-of-binding-errors-for-a-json-form-in-spring-mvc

Comment: I know this is a couple years old now, but a search brought me here. If I get time, I'll try to turn this into an answer, but in the mean time, I wrote a blog post about doing this kind of thing specifically when Jackson is the underlying JSON lib with Spring: https://dougbreaux.github.io/2020/10/11/Additional-Jackson-Parse-Errors.html

Answer (score 5):

See if the `HttpMessageNotReadableException.getCause()` is useful. Depending on your underlying JSON library, it might give you what you want. In the case of Jackson JSON parsing, I found that some of the Jackson-specific Exceptions do have field-level information.

For instance,

```java
        Throwable cause = e.getCause();

        if (cause instanceof JsonParseException) {
            JsonParseException jpe = (JsonParseException) cause;
            msg = jpe.getOriginalMessage();
        }
```

[Jackson Javadoc](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.13/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonProcessingException.html#getOriginalMessage--).

I discuss this a bit [in a Blog post](https://dougbreaux.github.io/2020/10/11/Additional-Jackson-Parse-Errors.html).

Answer (score 1):

In my case this was the complete solution the code of @dbreaux help a lot to understand how te get the fields.

Just override the method below in you ControllerAdvice

```
@Override
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleHttpMessageNotReadable(@NotNull HttpMessageNotReadableException ex, @NotNull HttpHeaders headers, @NotNull HttpStatus status, @NotNull WebRequest request) {
    String propertyName = null;

    if (ex.getCause() instanceof UnrecognizedPropertyException instanceOfUnrecognizedPropertyException) {
        propertyName = instanceOfUnrecognizedPropertyException.getPropertyName();
    }

    Message message = "Field " + propertyName + " does not exists";

    return handleExceptionInternal(ex, message, headers, status, request);
}
```